# Softlayer API timeout

Tags: python, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am using Softlayer Python API to pull hardware details. The script exits midway with below API error. I have rate-limited the number of servers to as low as 10, but still it errors.

Is there a way we can close/disconnect the connection to api ?
For example how do I close the "client" explicitly in below ?
Any help to overcome this ?

```
client = SoftLayer.Client(username=USER, api_key=API_KEY,timeout = 1000)

hardware = client['Account'].getHardware(mask='id, fullyQualifiedDomainName,operatingSystem.softwareLicense.softwareDescription.longDescription,hardwareChassis.manufacturer,hardwareChassis.name,hardwareChassis.version,networkComponents.primaryIpAddress,processorCount,datacenter.name,primaryBackendIpAddress,motherboard.hardwareComponentModel.longDescription,processors.hardwareComponentModel.longDescription,memory.hardwareComponentModel.longDescription,memory.hardwareComponentModel.capacity,raidControllers.hardwareComponentModel.longDescription,hardDrives.hardwareComponentModel.longDescription',limit=limit,offset=offset);


File "/usr/local/bin/inv.py", line 90, in fetch_hw
hardware = client['Account'].getHardware(mask='id, fullyQualifiedDomainName,operatingSystem.softwareLicense.softwareDescription.longDescription,hardwareChassis.manufacturer,hardwareChassis.name,hardwareChassis.version,networkComponents.primaryIpAddress,processorCount,datacenter.name,primaryBackendIpAddress,motherboard,processors,memory,raidControllers,hardDrives',limit=limit,offset=offset);
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SoftLayer/API.py", line 392, in call_handler
return self(name, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SoftLayer/API.py", line 360, in call
return self.client.call(self.name, name, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SoftLayer/API.py", line 263, in call
return self.transport(request)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SoftLayer/transports.py", line 199, in __call__
raise exceptions.TransportError(0, str(ex))
SoftLayer.exceptions.TransportError: TransportError(0): ("Connection broken: error(104, 'Connection reset by peer')", error(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))
```

Answer (score 0):

There is not a way to close/disconnect the client when a process is running.

I was able to reproduce the error with more than 150 hardware items, not less. Sometimes it takes more time to get all data because your mask is very long, I suggest to reduce it as much as you can.

The Internet connection may be affecting the results you are getting, I suggest review it.

If you want to get all BMS, you can try by getting all of them part by part, below you can see an example. 
If error persists you can try by retrieving them one by one (limit=1)

```
"""
List Bare Metal servers.

The script retrieve all bare metal servers part by part in order to avoid time out
errors.

Important manual pages:
https://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account
https://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getHardware
https://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatype/SoftLayer_Hardware/
https://sldn.softlayer.com/article/object-masks
https://sldn.softlayer.com/article/object-filters

License: http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/License
Author: SoftLayer Technologies, Inc. <sldn@softlayer.com>
"""
import SoftLayer

# Your SoftLayer API username and key.
USERNAME = 'set-me'
API_KEY = 'set-me'

# The limit and offset of resultLimit feature.
limit = 10
offset = 0

# The array where all SoftLayer_Hardware objects will be stored.
hardware = []

# Flag to know if there are still SoftLayer_Hardware
has_items = True

# Create client instance
client = SoftLayer.create_client_from_env(username=USERNAME, api_key=API_KEY)

object_mask = 'id,fullyQualifiedDomainName,operatingSystem.softwareLicense' \
              '.softwareDescription.longDescription,hardwareChassis.manufacturer,' \
              'hardwareChassis.name,hardwareChassis.version,networkComponents' \
              '.primaryIpAddress,processorCount,datacenter.name,' \
              'primaryBackendIpAddress,motherboard.hardwareComponentModel' \
              '.longDescription,processors.hardwareComponentModel.longDescription,' \
              'memory.hardwareComponentModel.longDescription,' \
              'memory.hardwareComponentModel.capacity,raidControllers' \
              '.hardwareComponentModel.longDescription,hardDrives' \
              '.hardwareComponentModel.longDescription'

try:
    """
    Following loop helps to retrieve all data part by part. This example shows how
    to retrieve each 10 objects. Just change limit value if you want to
    increase or decrease the number of retrieved data.
    """
    while has_items:
        hardware_items = client['SoftLayer_Account'].getHardware(mask=object_mask,
                                                                 limit=limit,
                                                                 offset=offset)
        hardware.extend(hardware_items)

        if len(hardware_items) > 0:
            offset += limit
        else:
            has_items = False

    print(hardware)

except SoftLayer.SoftLayerAPIError as e:
    """
    If there was an error returned from the SoftLayer API then bomb out with
    the error message.
    """
    print("Unable to get SoftLayer_Hardware objects: %s, %s " % (e.faultCode,
                                                                 e.faultString))
```

I hope this help you.

Regards.